# how to use custom block variables area in theme block

Tags: theming, 7

I installed the module "theme block". there is an area called "custom block variables". Does anyone know what is it and how to use it? I would like to create a custom block to see a portion of an article that I wrote and I want see a picture. It can serve me?
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like a view. May you be more specific?

Comment: yes, I think you're right. Where can I learn more?